# Unable to issue any AT commands to BT BLE Breakout Board

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I'm a programmer, more from the software side but I do have hardware working knowledge too. I've completed the Arduino Starter Kit's 15 projects, Now trying to build some things with ESP8266 and HM-10 BLE.

I was able to connect ESP8266 to my network and start a TCP server too via AT commands(using  Arduino's Serial Monitor and FTDI 232RL USB to TTL converter)

I also have a HM-10 Bluetooth Breakout+connector board (Its based on CC2541 by TI (visible on the SMD chip)) brought from [here](http://www.amazon.in/ePro-Labs-Module-Connector-Board-Bluetooth/dp/B019WEUY6O).

Using the same setup I was able to issue AT commands successfully for ESP8266. However I tried many things, different baud rates and \r\n combinations; I just couldnt get the HM-10 to acknowledge my AT commands.

Setup: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q90QO.jpg)

Connections:

```
Arduino +5V --> +ve input of LDO regulator --> 3.3v OUPUT to Vcc of HM-10
Common GND for LDO regulator input and output pins, FTDI 232RL and HM10

FTDI TX --> voltage divider (1k ohms --> connection output to HM 10 RX --> 1k ohms --> 1k ohms --> GND)
```

There is no code/sketch as of now. I'm just trying to hook up the HM-10 BLE chip. I can pair my Android phone to it but that's not the concern here.

The concern here is I cannot configure the HM-10 using AT commands.

The HM-10 does not reply an "OK" acknowledge for my "AT" command. Nothing happens in the serial monitor after hitting enter. Just a blank screen.

Is there a way by which I can determine what baud rate to use and what combination of \r and \n?

What am I missing here?

Comment: You might find this helpful: ftp://imall.iteadstudio.com/Modules/IM130614001_Serial_Port_BLE_Module_Master_Slave_HM-10/DS_IM130614001_Serial_Port_BLE_Module_Master_Slave_HM-10.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that there is no need for a voltage divider to reduce the voltage being given to RX pin of BLE from FTDI's TX since both FTDI232RL and HM-10 are 3.3V devices (from [here](http://arduino-er.blogspot.in/2015/12/test-hm-10-bluetooth-40-ble-module-with.html))

I connected the TX from FTDI directly to the RX of BLE using female to female jumpers.

Used `No Line Ending` and 9600 as the baud rate.

Then it worked fine, I got an `OK` acknowledge for my `AT` command.